# 18/4 connector for repeated plugging and unplugging?

Tags: connector, power-delivery, power-connector

I'm designing a device for off-grid DC power delivery. Because this is a fairly specialized system that wants to minimize complexity and whatnot, the plan is for the power supply and load to be decoupled, with a bare minimum of circuitry on the load side. Accordingly, the plan is to connect the two with 18/4 (18 AWG, four wires) wiring which can be plugged in and unplugged as needed.

Requirements:

- Suitable for 18/4 wire
- Rated for at least 1000 plug/unplug cycles
- Rated for at least 12 V / ~2 W (~200 mA)
- Ideally neither the inner nor outer insulation jackets are exposed ("looks finished")
- Should be "easy" to plug and unplug (screwing on is okay — "easy" doesn't have to mean "quick" — but having to struggle to get it to let go is undesirable)
- Mechanical (not just solder) connection between the plug and wires would be preferred
- Ideally can be flush-mounted to a housing
- *Optionally* dust-proof; does *not* need to be waterproof

Possibilities:

- [Molex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molex_connector) Mate-n-Lok
- [Molex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molex_connector) Mini-Fit Jr.
- [SATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#SATA_power)
- "Kycon"
- [XLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLR_connector)
- GX16/GX20/GM21/GM21
- [NMEA 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_2000)

Would any of these be suitable? Mate-n-Lok are a PITA and I've heard Mini-Fit Jr. isn't suitable for repeated plugging and unplugging, plus neither of them would look "finished". I'm not very familiar with the others.

Comment: i don't know if this would comply with electrical code ... if you are in north america, then use a european power outlet and vice versa ... cut the female end from one of these to get a finished power cord ... https://www.datapro.net/catalog/international-power-cables.html

Comment: Consider XLRs - tough , and there's a 4-pin version.

Comment: Product recommendation questions are considered off topic here.  What you could do is make a survey of what is typically used in situations of similar need.  Especially as your requirements seem incompletely developed, you may do well to look at an example in use and say "yes that fits my goals" or "no, it's almost right but this one aspect would be a problem"

Comment: @ChrisStratton, incomplete in what way? What am I missing? The problem is I don't really *know* what's out there. I know PC connectors but I've heard those may not be suitable for my use. I know standard power plugs, but I don't think those are ideal either (bulky, hard to find anything with 4 pins). Something like Brian's suggestion to look at XLR is helpful.

Comment: Incomplete in the sense that you don't really know what you want, but rather all of your challenging criteria are vague or "nice to have".  Looking at what is out there is indeed what you need to do in order to make a good choice.  But that is *not the purpose of this site*, which is rather reserved only for specific and specifically answerable questions to the explicit *exclusion* of "shopping questions".

Comment: @BrianDrummond:  I don't think 4 #18 wires would fit in a 4 pin XLR connector.

Comment: I'm partial to Anderson's Powerpole connectors.

Comment: @Hearth, huh, I saw those and didn't think they'd be durable, but 10k (cold) mating cycles? Care to write that up as an answer?

Comment: @PeterBennett I just looked up #18 and it's tiny, < 1mm^2, so there's surely no problem there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm rather partial to [Anderson's Powerpole connectors](https://www.andersonpower.com/shop/wire-to-wire/powerpole.html), which are highly durable connectors rated for thousands of mating cycles, are modular so you can assemble your own four-pole connector out of four single-pole ones, and are symmetric so there's no plug and socket, just a single connector that mates with another identical one. The contacts are crimped onto the cable, so they do fit your mechanical-connection requirement, though you would want a specialized tool for crimping them. (Powerwerx makes [one](https://powerwerx.com/tricrimp-powerpole-connector-crimping-tool), as well as [a different one](https://powerwerx.com/hex-crimping-tool-sb-series-powerpole) for the high current connectors, so you don't need to spend thousands on an official Anderson one.)

Plus they're super cheap. I've never seen another connector rated for similar voltage and current that costs anywhere near as little as these do.

I've used them before as the only affordable connector I could find for 100 amp contacts, and they worked fantastically in that role, though the larger ones *do* start to require a fair bit of force to connect and disconnect. Even the smallest ones (15 amp) are probably far overkill for your purposes though.

Disclaimer: I am in no way affiliated with either Anderson Power Products or Powerwerx; I've merely found their products useful enough to recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Neutrik Speak-On connector. Extremely reliable.

These are available in 4-pin and 8-pin.

Pull back on the lock latch and rotate about 1/8 turn counter-clockwise, then pull out.

These are used in Professional Audio and have proven to be extremely reliable.

Comment: MC rating? 5,000+. Current rating? Up to 40A. Mechanical connection? Appears to use screw-down; bonus! Pretty? Yup. Easy? Sounds like it. Looks ***very*** promising; thanks! (Chances I would have found this on my own? Exceedingly low...)

Comment: Never used Speak-On personally, but I have heard good things about them!

Answer (score 0):

The connector type that you may want to consider has been around for a long time, is rugged, is low cost and is available in a plethora of styles. The styles include chassis/panel mount for one end of your DC power connection. The other end that would cable mounted can be obtained in a variety of styles with connector back shells or custom over molded ends.

What I am proposing is to consider using a DSub-9 type as pictured below.

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://www.google.com/search?q=DSub-9+connector)*</sup>

The style shown has solder cup pins but you can also get crimp and insert pins. Cheaper connectors use rolled metal contacts whilst more expensive ones can be found with turned metal solid contacts.

These can be used with thumb or jack screws to ensure the connection stays mated.

And finally you may want to consider the fact that you can use pairs of contacts for each wire.

Despite the fact that these connectors have been used for everything under the sun you should be fine using these for your application if you use common sense in your use and guidance documentation for the application.

Comment: I don't think that meets the mating cycles requirement? Cursory research suggests D-Sub is rated for ~200-300, which is well below the desired 1,000.

Comment: Bahhh - Look at style with turned solid metal contacts that are gold plated. The limited research you did is for the cheapest formed contacts that have the absolute bare minimum flash or cheap dip plating.

Comment: Citation needed. (Okay, I meant 200-500, but that's still sort-of low.) If you know a source that's better rated, please share.

Answer (score 0):

Mini-Fit Jr. *might* work.

Let's see:

> Suitable for 18/4 wire

Check. 18 AWG (and even 16 AWG) stranded wire  is pretty common for PC power wiring.

> Rated for at least 1000 plug/unplug cycles

Well... standard pins are rated for... 30 cycles . However, pins rated for 1,500 cycles [are available](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/part-detail/crimp_terminals/0460183541).

> Rated for at least 12 V / ~2 W (~200 mA)

Yup; rated for quite a bit more in fact.

> Ideally neither the inner nor outer insulation jackets are exposed ("looks finished")

Well... no dice here, at least as far as the outer jacketing. However, ribbon cables are available

> Should be "easy" to plug and unplug (screwing on is okay — "easy" doesn't have to mean "quick" — but having to struggle to get it to let go is undesirable)

These can be finicky if they're difficult to access, but they aren't as bad as Mate-n-Lok, especially if there is plenty of clearance around the connection.

> Mechanical (not just solder) connection between the plug and wires would be preferred

Mini-Fit Jr. uses crimped connections.

> Ideally can be flush-mounted to a housing

Yup; see any ATX PSU.

> Optionally dust-proof; does not need to be waterproof

Probably not.